Remove the severity of the error from error message send by Postgresql
Is there a way to remove the "ERROR:" from the error message that postgresql sends? Adding a sample error message :
ERROR: insert or update on table "bonus" violates foreign key constraint "bonus_cust_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (cust_id)=(1998) is not present in table "customer"

All SQLException seems to be starting with "ERROR:" and I am exploring options if it can be removed through superuser. The documentation here mentions about configuring the logger levels through superuser, so I am thinking if there is an option to remove "ERROR:" keyword from message.
I have further explained this issue here and was advised to ask here.
If it cannot be done by superuser, then is there a way to modify it through code? I am using java and jdbc.
This is the method from QueryExecutorImpl class where error message is created:
private SQLException receiveErrorResponse() throws IOException {
        int elen = this.pgStream.receiveInteger4();

        assert elen > 4 : "Error response length must be greater than 4";

        EncodingPredictor.DecodeResult totalMessage = this.pgStream.receiveErrorString(elen - 4);
        ServerErrorMessage errorMsg = new ServerErrorMessage(totalMessage);
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, " <=BE ErrorMessage({0})", errorMsg.toString());
        }

        PSQLException error = new PSQLException(errorMsg, this.logServerErrorDetail);
        if (this.transactionFailCause == null) {
            this.transactionFailCause = error;
        } else {
            error.initCause(this.transactionFailCause);
        }

        return error;
    }

Just thinking, if there is a way in java to intercept and change when the error message is created.

I don't see how this applies to this site better than SE, but whatever. Have you done research in how to modify messages from PostgreSQL? Where are you observing these errors? If you're reading through a log file to see these errors, could you grab that log file and sanitize it to remove the info? Understanding your end goal may help us find a better solution overall.
